# Looping VBScript

Tags: loops, vbscript, syntax-error

I'm trying to run a VBScript checking the time until it reaches 22:00 (10PM), and then runs `shutdown.bat`. I always get errors such as "'loop' without 'do'". Can anyone look at my code and see if there's a way to fix it?

```
Do 
    If Hour(Time()) => 22 And Minute(Time()) => 30 And Hour(Time()) < 23 Then
Loop Until True
    Then
        'Dim shell
        Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        shell.Run "shutdown.bat"
        Set shell = Nothing
    End If
```

Comment: use the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://www.evermap.com/AutoBatchUseTaskScheduler.asp) for that

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to keep a loop running until it reaches a specific hour, here's how it's done:

```
Do While True ' = Do the following forever (or until something breaks the loop)
    If Hour(Time()) => 22 And Minute(Time()) => 30 And Hour(Time()) < 23 Then
        ' Do whatever you want and then
        ' break the loop:
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

However, I wouldn't recommend that because it will consume much resources. Instead, you should be using [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `Do Until True` instead of `Do While True` or are the two interchangeable?

Comment: @H3153N, `While True` doesn't mean "while the condition is true". `While True` is always true, so you're basically running the loop infinitely until something breaks it. I added an explanation to my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Loop until the current time is greater than your desired end time:

```
endtime = CDate("22:30")
Do Until Time > endtime
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "shutdown.bat"
```

Using `WScript.Sleep` inside the loop ensures that the loop doesn't do a burn-in on the CPU.

However, as [@AhmedAbdelhameed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41916422/1630171) already mentioned, creating a scheduled task that runs `shutdown.bat` at the desired time would usually be far more efficient.